# UFT API -- "Select data" How to return values for query to Sybase database

Tags: hp-uft

I have to validate an API output with a values stored in Sybase DB.

When I use "select Data" activity to fetch the value from Sybase table, the value is returned in XML format as below:

```
<Row>
     <ColumnName1> Value </ColumnName1>
     <ColumnName2> Value </ColumnName2>
     <ColumnName3> Value </ColumnName3>
</Row>
```

However I need only the Value so I can save it in excel to compare in my next step. Comparison is being done on value basis not with xml. I need to convert the response from select data (which is in XML format shown above) .

The subsequent checkpoint in API output fails as I need to provide individual values as input to the service.

I will need a solution that can either split array and give me individual values at run time Or I should be able to save values in Excel which I can save and import at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COM object for Microsoft's XML Parser. Something like this should do it,

```
    set objXml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objXml.Load("C:\yourxmlpath.xml")

    ' Get your node (you can traverse it like a path)
    set allMathchingRows = objXml.selectNodes("/Row")


    For intRow = 0 To allMathchingRows.Length - 1
        For each Node in allMathchingRows(intRow).ChildNodes
            strAllRowData = strAllRowData + "," + Node.text             
        Next    
        ' Remove the ' appended to the start of string 
        strAllRowData = Right(strAllRowData, Len(strAllRowData) - 1) 
    Next
```

you may want to refine it more if you want your data separate for each rows